# How can I retrieve all data and label the one that are the newest as the new data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Standards that includes ID, StandardsFamiliy, Standards,Date and Link.
I want to show all data, but I want the newest date in same StandardsFamily and Standards labeled as the newest one.
For example if I have

```
StandardFamily,  Standards, Date
A                   a        2018
A                   a        2017
B                   b        2016
C                   c        2010
C                   c        2011
C                   c        2011
C                   c2       2018
```

I want to retrieve this:

```
StandardFamily,  Standards, Date,  Status
A                   a        2018   New
A                   a        2017   Old
B                   b        2016   New
C                   c        2010   Old
C                   c        2011   Old
C                   c        2012   New
C                   c2       2018   New
```

I know how to retrieve only the newest one with following query:

```
select * 
from Standards
where (StandardFamily,Standards,Date) 
IN (select StandardFamily,Standards,Max(Date) from Standards group by StandardFamily,Standards)
```

I think I might to follow something like

```
select
case when (...) then "New" else "Old" end
from Table
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you would simply use `row_number()`:

```
select s.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by StandardFamily, Standards order by date desc) = 1
             then 'New' else 'Old'
        end) as status
from standards s;
```

In earlier versions, I think I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (case when date = (select max(s2.date)
                          from standards s2
                          where s2.StandardFamily = s.StandardFamily and
                                s2.Standards = s.Standards
                          )
              then 'New' else 'Old'
        end) as status
from standards s;
```

In particular, this can make good use of an index on `(StandardFamily, Standards, Date)`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time! I will learn more about row_number. Thank you soo soo much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get these results by `LEFT JOIN`ing to a list of `MAX(Date)` grouped by `StandardFamily` and `Standard`, and then checking for `NULL` values in the other table (only the entries with the newest `Date` will have non-NULL values):

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN s1.StandardFamily IS NULL THEN "Old" ELSE "New" END AS Status
FROM Standards s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT StandardFamily, Standards, MAX(Date) AS Date
           FROM Standards
           GROUP BY StandardFamily, Standards) s1 ON s1.StandardFamily = s.StandardFamily AND s1.Standards = s.Standards AND s1.Date = s.Date
```

Output:

```
StandardFamily  Standards   Date    Status
A               a           2018    New
A               a           2017    Old
B               b           2016    New
C               c           2010    Old
C               c           2011    Old
C               c           2012    New
C               c2          2018    New
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/woWmNWMr3wfFiJoZmMWKGu/1)

Comment: Hi, I have a question, why you wrote "IS NULL"? I cannot undrestand how the value may be NULL

Comment: @K.Moshar when you do a `LEFT JOIN` and there is no matching row in the second table, the values that would have come from that table are all replaced with `NULL`. In this case, the second table (`s1`) only contains the most recent dates, so any row in the first table which didn't have the most recent date would have `NULL` values for `s1`. So we can check if `s1.StandardFamily` is `NULL`, and if it is, that means the value is `Old`.